# Time efficient way to convert PDF to image

Tags: python, image, pdf, ocr, pdf2image

**Context:**

I have PDF files I'm working with.
I'm using an `ocr` to extract the text from these documents and to be able to do that I have to convert my pdf files to images.
I currently use the `convert_from_path` function of the `pdf2image` module but it is very time inefficient (9minutes for a 9page pdf).

**Problem:**

I am looking for a way to accelerate this process or another way to convert my PDF files to images.

**Additional info:**

I am aware that there is a `thread_count` parameter in the function but after several tries it doesn't seem to make any difference.

This is the whole function I am using:

```
def pdftoimg(fic,output_folder):
# Store all the pages of the PDF in a variable 
pages = convert_from_path(fic, dpi=500,output_folder=output_folder,thread_count=9, poppler_path=r'C:\Users\Vincent\Documents\PDF\poppler-21.02.0\Library\bin') 

image_counter = 0

# Iterate through all the pages stored above 
for page in pages: 
    filename = "page_"+str(image_counter)+".jpg"
    page.save(output_folder+filename, 'JPEG') 
    image_counter = image_counter + 1
    
for i in os.listdir(output_folder):
    if i.endswith('.ppm'):
        os.remove(output_folder+i)
```

[Link](https://pdf2image.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html) to the convert_from_path reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an answer to that problem using another module called `fitz` which is a python binding to `MuPDF`.

**First of all install PyMuPDF:**

The documentation can be found [here](https://documentation.help/PyMuPDF/installation.html#installbinary) but for windows users it's rather simple:

```
pip install PyMuPDF
```

**Then import the fitz module:**

```
import fitz
print(fitz.__doc__)

>>>PyMuPDF 1.18.13: Python bindings for the MuPDF 1.18.0 library.
>>>Version date: 2021-05-05 06:32:22.
>>>Built for Python 3.7 on win32 (64-bit).
```

**Open your file and save every page as images:**

The get_pixmap() method accepts different parameters that allows you to control the image (variation,resolution,color...) so I suggest that you red the documentation [here](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html).

```
def convert_pdf_to_image(fic):
    #open your file
    doc = fitz.open(fic)
    #iterate through the pages of the document and create a RGB image of the page
    for page in doc:
        pix = page.get_pixmap()
        pix.save("page-%i.png" % page.number)
```

Hope this helps anyone else.

Comment: time inefficient is caused by dpi ,in your function you set dpi=500 in convert_from_path this mean your result has very good quality
if you change it to 200 dpi (default value) you got the same results like  fitz

Comment: Note PyMuPDF's license. It's AGPL for commercial and such may require you to buy a license if you want to use it.

Comment: If you need better quality go for pd2image (convert_from_path() or conver_from_bytes() ), but it's slower than fitz.